# Appending hex value to string

Tags: perl, ascii

```
$temp = 'abc'.0x12;
print $temp; # prints abc18
```

While appending the hex value to string it is getting converted to decimal value and final result is string. what I want is that the ascii value of the hex should get appended to the string.

for e.g. 0x12 in ascii is DC2 (device control 2).

Comment: Have you tried using `sprintf` with the proper formatter? In this case `%x` for hex in lowercase, `%X` if you want uppercase hex letters. Reference: [http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

Comment: @SlyRaskal: I am giving the $temp as input to program, which doesn't accept the strings with special characters. In python I m doing 'tab\x12' which is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Sly Raskal was on the right track but instead of `%x` use `%c`, so:

```
my $hex = 0x12;
my $ascii = sprintf "%c", $hex;
my $temp = 'abc' . $ascii;
```

I think this gives the result you were looking for. I got it from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=191039 .

Comment: Looks like ali0sha has given a much better response!

Answer (score 3):

Try using chr:

```
my $a = 'abc'.chr 0x3e;
print $a;
```