# Fully Qualified name while using inline python

Tags: perl

```
use Inline Python => <<'END';
   from MYPYTHONLIBRARY import *
END



my $Obj = MYPYTHONLIBRARY->new($a, $b);       # line 30
```

the error I am getting is:
Can't locate object method "`new`" via package "`MYPYTHONLIBRARY`" `(perhaps you forgot to load "MYPYTHONLIBRARY "?) at /MY/LIBRARY/PATH/MYPERLLIBRARY.pm line 30`.

So i searched on net and found that

"Inline::Python inspects the main namespace of the Python code and imports 
those names into the current package. Thus you have to specify the fully 
qualified name of the imported class:

```
package TestPy;
use Inline Python => 'from StringIO import StringIO';
my $stringio = TestPy::StringIO->new;"
```

•Markdown [example link](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.inline/2014/02/msg4524.html)

My problem is that, in my code there is lot of do and require statement and I am not able to get the fully qualified name.

```
Fully::Qualified::name::MYPYTHONLIBRARY->new($a, $b);
```

So how can I get the fully qualified name for my python library.

Comment: Can you just use "stock" python?

Comment: @keith: I don't understand. what do you mean by "stock", is this a package or something.

Comment: I mean the code you are showing is not Python. Any reason you can't just use regular Python?

Comment: You may have to add the directory
containing your modules to the PYTHONPATH env variable or modify
sys.path from right in the Inline Python.   You could play with
something like

`    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Inline Python => <<END;
    import sys
    print sys.path
    END`

to see the search path you're already getting from Inline and if maybe
the code you want is somewhere in there?

Comment: @Keith: I have test framework written in perl. But having problem in automating few test cases of type [Test]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498384/appending-hex-value-to-string/27500528#27500528). So I have written a python lib and want use it with perl framework

Answer (score 1):

```
from MYPYTHONLIBRARY import *
...
...
my $Obj = MYPYTHONLIBRARY->new($a, $b);
```

You are importing the names defined *INSIDE* a file called `MYPYTHONLIBRARY.py`.  Do you have a class inside that file named MYPYTHONLIBRARY?  I doubt it.

Here is an example of what you should be doing:

```
~/perl_programs$ ls 9.pl python_lib.py
9.pl        python_lib.py


~/perl_programs$ cat python_lib.py
def greet():
    print "hello"

class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

~/perl_programs$ cat 9.pl
use Inline Python; 

my $d = Dog->new("Sam");
print $d->get_name() . "\n";

greet();
__END__
__Python__
from python_lib import *

~/perl_programs$ perl 9.pl 
Sam
hello
```

By the way, you should NEVER use `from abc import *` in a python program, and you shouldn't do it when using inline python, either.

> So how can I get the fully qualified name for my python library.

You don't need the fully qualified name for your *python* library--you need the name of the perl package into which you are importing the python.

> My problem is that, in my code there is lot of do and require
>   statement and I am not able to get the fully qualified name.

How about a simple example?

Comment: I do have a class in MYPYTHONLIBRARY.py. [example link](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.inline/2014/02/msg4524.html)

Comment: I do have a class in MYPYTHONLIBRARY.py.Please go through this thread  [example link](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.inline/2014/02/msg4524.html). You're running your program the main package that's why it is giving no problem. I am using inline python inside a module and wasn't able to resolve the FQN for my python lib.